# Why does Ubuntu ignore my xorg.conf?

Tags: 12.04, nvidia, resolution, hdmi

Hi my Ubuntu has developed a strange problem. It just ignores my xorg setting and falls back to what I presume is a hardware default setting.

In more detail when I do a clean install it automatically sets my resolution to 1920x1080i @60hz, I then change this to 1920x1080p @60hz but this causes the resolution to set its self to 1920x1080i @50hz after a reboot, and then no matter what I set the xorg to it always boots at this resolution.

I can change the setting in the `nvidia-settings` dialog (yes I have ran it as root) but it never saves my setting and falls back to this resolution.

Heres some system spec : 2x P4ht @ 3ghz
                         Nvidia g force 310 via hdmi
                         Connected to a HD 1080p tv

I really hope someone can help as this is a real pain.

Heres a link to my xorg set up for 1080p @50hz http://paste.ubuntu.com/1146394/

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Change the resolution in the Displays pane in system settings. I don't think Xorg.conf is actually used anymore.

Comment: Xorg is not used by default, but if you create one at /etc/x11 ubuntu should use this by default as my card is nvidia xserver is in charge of the graphics. The resolution is set in display settings but I canot change the V refresh or choose I or P there.

Comment: Please include the contents of your `xorg.conf` file in your question.